# How to filter table rows based on multiple select fields?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a small project to create a table that can be filtered using 2 select inputs.

I've used some code I found on a similar question here and tried modifying it. The first select input works perfectly but I can't seem to get the second to work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<script>
function searchTable() {
    var input, filter, inputtwo, filtertwo, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    inputtwo = document.getElementById("myInput2");
    filtertwo = inputtwo.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        } else {
            if (tr[i].id != 'tableHeader'){tr[i].style.display = "none";}
        }
    }
}
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Filtered Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
#myInput {
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}
#myInput2 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
#name {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><select id="myInput" onchange="searchTable()" placeholder="Role Category..">
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="Leadership">Leadership</option>
    <option value="Infrastructure">Infrastructure</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td width="50%"><select id="myInput2" onchange="searchTable()" placeholder="Role Category..">
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="South East">South East</option>
              </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="tableHeader" class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;"><span style="width:40%;">Role Category</span></th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Role</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Region</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Lower Quartile</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Median</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Upper quartle</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£145,000</td>
    <td>£185,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£135,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£95,000</td>
    <td>£140,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£134,259</td>
    <td>£171,296</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>


    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£125,000</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£87,963</td>
    <td>£129,630</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£145,000</td>
    <td>£185,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£135,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£95,000</td>
    <td>£140,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£134,259</td>
    <td>£171,296</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£125,000</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£87,963</td>
    <td>£129,630</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the refactor of your `searchTable` function below. You can use the [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class selector to target specific table data elements (the first among siblings is the one that you seem to want to target with the first filter, and the third is the one for the second filter).

The `shouldBeVisible` variable is created from a compound condition: whether the text in both elements match the corresponding filters. This is essential to using the combination of both filters to show/hide elements.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<script>

function searchTable () {
  const filter1 = document.getElementById("myInput").value.trim();
  const filter2 = document.getElementById("myInput2").value.trim();

  const tableRows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (const tr of tableRows) {
    if (tr.id === 'tableHeader') continue;

    const td1 = tr.querySelector("td:nth-of-type(1)");
    const td2 = tr.querySelector("td:nth-of-type(3)");

    const shouldBeVisible = (
      td1.textContent.trim().includes(filter1)
      && td2.textContent.trim().includes(filter2)
    );

    tr.style.display = shouldBeVisible ? "" : "none";
  }
}

</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Filtered Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
#myInput {
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}
#myInput2 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
#name {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><select id="myInput" onchange="searchTable()" placeholder="Role Category..">
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="Leadership">Leadership</option>
    <option value="Infrastructure">Infrastructure</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td width="50%"><select id="myInput2" onchange="searchTable()" placeholder="Role Category..">
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="South East">South East</option>
              </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="tableHeader" class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;"><span style="width:40%;">Role Category</span></th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Role</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Region</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Lower Quartile</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Median</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Upper quartle</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£145,000</td>
    <td>£185,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£135,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£95,000</td>
    <td>£140,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£134,259</td>
    <td>£171,296</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>


    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£125,000</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leadership</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£87,963</td>
    <td>£129,630</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£145,000</td>
    <td>£185,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£100,000</td>
    <td>£135,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>£95,000</td>
    <td>£140,000</td>
    <td>£180,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Technology Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£134,259</td>
    <td>£171,296</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£92,593 </td>
    <td>£125,000</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Infrastructure</td>
    <td>Chief Information Security Officer </td>
    <td>South East</td>
    <td>£87,963</td>
    <td>£129,630</td>
    <td>£166,667</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Update: If you add more filters in the future, you'll see more duplicated code in the loop — you can reduce it by using a pattern like this:

```js
// ---snip---

if (tr.id === 'tableHeader') continue;

const shouldBeVisible = [
  ["td:nth-of-type(1)", filter1],
  ["td:nth-of-type(3)", filter2],
].every(([selector, filter]) => {
  const td = tr.querySelector(selector)!;
  return td.textContent.trim().includes(filter);
});

tr.style.display = shouldBeVisible ? "" : "none";

// ---snip---
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks so much! Going to spend some time tomorrow making sure I understand it.